# Data Factory DataSet timezone handling

Tags: c#, datetime, timezone, azure-data-factory

When having input CSV data (in blob storage) with the timezone offset e.g.

2018-08-29T06:38:19+01:00

And the dataset has the culture en-GB for the column.

i.e.

```
      {
        "name": "TransactionDateTime",
        "type": "Datetime",
        "culture": "en-gb"
      },
```

It lands in ADLS as:

2018-08-29 05:38:19.0000000

It looks like it's being parsed as +1 and then written as UTC, even though the output dataset culture is en-gb.

We have mostly set en-gb as the default in data factory is en-us which isn't a sensible default for us.

The data factory documentation suggests looking at the c# documentation for format strings, so I assume it's using the .net framework implementation.

> If s contains no time zone information, the Kind property of the
>   returned DateTime object is DateTimeKind.Unspecified. This behavior
>   can be changed by using the DateTimeStyles.AssumeLocal flag, which
>   returns a DateTime value whose Kind property is DateTimeKind.Local, or
>   by using the DateTimeStyles.AssumeUniversal and
>   DateTimeStyles.AdjustToUniversal flags, which returns a DateTime value
>   whose Kind property is DateTimeKind.Utc. If s contains time zone
>   information, the time is converted to local time, if necessary, and
>   the Kind property of the returned DateTime object is set to
>   DateTimeKind.Local. This behavior can be changed by using the
>   DateTimeStyles.RoundtripKind flag to not convert Coordinated Universal
>   Time (UTC) to a local time and to set the Kind property to
>   DateTimeKind.Utc.

Trying to repro this in c#, perhaps something like:

```
var inputInBlobDate = "2018-08-29T06:38:19+01:00";

var outputInADLSDate = "2018-08-29 05:38:19.0000000"; 

CultureInfo culture = new CultureInfo("en-GB");

var parsed = DateTime.ParseExact(inputInBlobDate, "yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssK", culture, DateTimeStyles.AdjustToUniversal);

parsed.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fffffff").Dump(); //2018-08-29 05:38:19.0000000
```

Are my theories correct that it's being written as UTC?

I'm concerned how British summer time is going to be handled if we specify the GB culture. Unless somehow GB culture is just the format string, but I can't see a format string like this in any of the CultureInfo so I don't think it is just for formatting.

Comment: output it as timestamp (int) if its possibe

Comment: Thanks @Steve I'm guessing this will be a timezone agnostic representation, although I was hoping to understand datetime handling in data factory.